# How to retrieve Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting error on this line:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();//erroris: create method getIntent()
```

Help me, if anybody knows in what case this error invokes??

My part of code:

Sender side:

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("code").equals("promo")) 
{
    String promocode = intent.getStringExtra("promocode");
    String isSMS = intent.getStringExtra("issms");
    String smsContent = intent.getStringExtra("smscon");
    String opCode = intent.getStringExtra("opcode");

    //send data
    Intent i=new Intent();
    i.putExtra("PROMOCODE", promocode);
    i.putExtra("SMSCONTENT", smsContent);
    i.putExtra("OPCODE", opCode);
```

Receiver side:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String promoCode = intent.getStringExtra("PROMOCODE");
String smsContent = intent.getStringExtra("SMSCONTENT");
String opCode = intent.getStringExtra("OPCODE");

String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notifications (" +
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            promoCode + "INTEGER," +
            smsContent + "TEXT," +
            opCode + "INTEGER);";
```

Comment: isnt the Intent i= new Intent() supposed to be Intent i = new Intnt(YourClass.this, MovingToClass.class) ??

Comment: @DharaShah read question properly

Comment: what class is this in? getIntent() is a method of an activity.

Comment: What is the error? Can u explain?

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting values, use this:-

String promocode = getIntent().getStringExtra("promocode");

change the key ("promocode") according to requirement.

tell me if this point helps you..

Comment: the key u are providing is correct or not? take care about uppercase and lower case letters.and put some more code of sender side activity.How you are starting next Activity